# Why does the Error List not give it's errors the number 1-x? But instead y-(y+x)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

At the moment I have 34 Errors in VS10. The "Error List" in Visual studio 2010 gives the errors numbers from 31-64, and not 1-34 as I would expect, why is that? Does anybody now?

At one point I had around ~150 errors, I don't know if it has anything to say, that the list was recently reduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because on the Error list tab, you can choose which 'errors' to show:

- Errors
- Warnings
- Messages

sometimes, when only one of the three is chosen, it will seem like the errors begin from a number which is not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you hiding warnings and informational messages?

If you had ~150 errors, I would say that it is likely that you have a few warnings in there.